# Data types for x86-64 processors

Tags: c, intrinsics, types

What are these data types for? __m64, __m128,
__m256 ?

Comment: It would help if you posted which programming language this was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick google-search gives me:

- [The __m64 data type is for use with the MMX and 3DNow! intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/08x3t697.aspx)
- [The __m128 data type, for use with the Streaming SIMD Extensions and Streaming SIMD Extensions 2 instructions intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx)

Unfortunately I can't readily find what __m256 is but I suspect it is along the same lines.

Basically, data structures for MMX and similar technologies.

Comment: __m256 is new extended data type in latest SIMD upgrade from intel

Comment: Of course, I searched for __m256 first and found the same stuff that you did.

Comment: Which, I should add, as you saw was not useful.  [sigh]

Answer (score 3):

[MMX Technology Packed Arithmetic Intrinsics (C++).](https://www.google.com/search?q=__m64)

Comment: Basically the answer is that they're enhanced datatypes intended for use in specialized processors, which have optimized instructions available for these types.

Answer (score 2):

they are [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) instructions, including new [AVX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) extension. http://www.serc.iisc.ernet.in/ComputingFacilities/systems/Dell_Doc/Intel_C++_Compiler/en_US/compiler_c/main_cls/intref_cls/common/intref_avx_details.htm and here

they store vectors - multiple values at the same time. you can do calculations on all values in a vector simultaneously with special instructions. Chech links